# An algorithm for parsing a text

Tags: algorithm, parsing, text

I am parsing a text, now there is some challenge I came across:
The raw string in the text is

```
"All time views: 4,12011 shoppers saved this home"
```

I want to piece of code to recognize the meaning of this sentence, which is:

```
All time views: 4,120
11 shoppers saved this home
```

Ideally, I would like to return something like

```
{'views': 4,120, 'saved': 11}
```

This is hosing data, I have checked lots of records on their website and discovered that the 'All time views' is usually from 2 to  5 digits, and the 'shoppers saved' can be 1 or 2 digits.

PS: The raw text is obtained by removing all html tags from a web page, resulting in this kind of wired sentence structure. The raw html is:

```
<li>All time views: 4,120</li><li>11 shoppers saved this hom</li>
```

My team leader does not want to use html tag to parse the web page, since the the website regularly modified their htmls.

Any one has good idea? Any language or pseudocode or simple description of an algorithm would be fine. Thanks.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a space between 4,120 and 11? Or is there not a space in the raw text?

Comment: After removing the html tag, no space left. Originally, the html is <li>views...4,120</li><li>11 shopper saved</li>

Comment: May be I should keep all the <li> tags ?

Comment: Are you able to modify the html parser? That way I would suggest to add a "special character" after the first <li> tag, for example, a newline (\n). That way you get two lines and immediately know which line it is...

Comment: I'd modify the parser to generally replace tags with at least a space to avoid information loss in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should parse the raw html since the tags will generally help you.

In the case you presented, you can key off of the labels as long as the text is consistent from record to record.

Since you didn't ask for a specific language, I'll do this in general terms.

1) Isolate the html you need for one record (if it's one per page, that should be fine, if multiple, then use a string.split)

2) Find the index (starting character position) of "views:" and add 6 (including the space but you should test of course).  You will keep the string until you reach the "<".  That gives you the text representing views, which you can parse into a number if needed.

3) Find the index of "shoppers saved".  Then find everything before that until you reach the ">".  Most languages will make it easy to work backwards like that.  If you can't, then search for the first `<li>` after the previous index you got in step 2.  You may need to trim the space off the end.  That should result in the text representing the number of shoppers.

If you're going to do a lot of parsing, it will be worth your time to write a function where you can pass in the following parameters:

1) Full text to search
2) string to start from the end of (add the length to the index)
3) string to end at (don't add the length)

This will return everything in between the end of the start string and the start of the end string, which will cover simple efforts.  If you need more flexibility, you can add more parameters to help.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully you have a comma in your number, as noted by `4,12011`. When you have a comma, you know one thing: The number of numbers after is exactly 3.

> "All time views: 4,12011 shoppers saved this home"

You should look for the comma, using a method such a `lastIndexOf(',')`. This means that you'll get the last index of the comma, so if you have: `1,123,23223`, you will figure out it's beside the 3 and 2, and then you can parse out the remaining number.

This way you won't have to read the HTML tags (which would have been easier). The first string is input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf(',') + 3) and the other one is input.substring(input.lastIndexOf(',') + 3). This should work.

Note: For when the number of digits is ≤3, this method would not work. It wouldn't really be possible to figure it out without HTML tags. You can always try reading the HTML though, using `indexOf()` on the HTML tags.

Comment: You won't have a comma if you have less than 1,000 all time views though.

Comment: Yup, I mentioned that in the last sentence. But it wouldn't be possible to guess accurately what the numbers are.

Comment: Thanks both! I will utilize html tags, but the comma idea is really inspirational, I never thought of that. It should be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your team  leader that you must parse HTML in order to get the right results...

This code might help you:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.org/your-uri/';

//  loads the URL as an object
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);   
$dom = DomDocument::loadHTMLFile($url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

//  DomXPath helps you find the correct <ul> where those <li> are,
//  maybe by the <ul> ID or Class, so THIS xPath is only for explanation
//  it's not intended to work...
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$ul = $xpath->query("//html/body/the/path/to/the/ul[@id='TheIDoftheUL']/li");

//  Assuming that the <ul> has ONLY 2 <li> tags, as you stated...
$text = ['views' => $ul->item(0)->textContent, 'saved' => $ul->item(1)->textContent];
```

If the HTML changes in the future, you only need to restructure the xpath.

P.D. I just tested it and it works. I can pull 2 `<li>` from a blogroll  in my blog, (of course, I wrote the right path in the query method).